# ASP.NET Core Project with Angular (Code First) - Update child with composite key

Tags: angular, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, composite-primary-key, ef-fluent-api

I have the following models:

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Childs {get; set;}
    ...
    public Parent()
    {
        Childs = new Collection<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child {
    public string KeyB {get; set;}
    public int KeyA {get; set;}
    public Parent Parent {get; set;}
    public int ParentId
    ...
}
```

I used Fluent API to define the key for the Child:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
        .HasKey(b => new {b.ParentId, b.KeyA, b.KeyB});
}
```

The Controller for the parent for the Create-Action looks like this (child is same structure):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateParent([FromBody] SaveParentResource parentResource){
            
    var parent = mapper.Map<SaveParentResource, Parent>(parentResource);

    repository.Add(parent );
    await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

    parent = await repository.GetParent(parent.Id);

    var result = mapper.Map<Parent, ParentResource>(parent);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

The repository for the parent for the Create-Action looks like this (child is same structure):

```
public void Add(Parent parent)
{
    context.Parent.Add(parent);
}
```

To create a new child on typescript the code looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.parent.id)
      this.loadData()
}

private loadData(){
    this.childList = [];
    this.parentService.getParent(this.parent.id)
      .subscribe((parent: Parent) => {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.values.forEach(value => {
          this.childList.push({
            // Generates a list with filtered data from parent.Childs based on value
          });
        });
      });
}

saveParent(){
    var updatedParent: SaveParent = {
      id: this.parent.id,
      name: this.parent.name
    }
    if(updatedParent.id == 0) {
      this.parentService.create(updatedParent)
        .subscribe((parent: Parent) => {
          this.parent = parent;
          this.loadData();
        });
    } else {
      this.parentService.update(updatedParent)
        .subscribe((parent: Parent) => {
          this.loadData();
        });
    }
}

saveChild(child: Child){
    var updatedChild: Child = {
      keyB: child.keyB,
      keyA: child.keyA,
      parentId: this.parent.id
      ...
    }
    var previousChild = this.parent.childs.find(c => c.keyB == updatedChild.keyB)
    if(previousChild === undefined) {
      this.childService.create(updatedChild).subscribe();
    } else {
      this.childService.update(updatedChild).subscribe();
    }
}
```

When I now try to add a new child or update a child I will get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Childs_Parents_ParentId".
> The conflict occurred in database "TestDb", table "dbo.Parents", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

Testing the WebAPI with Postman seems to work for child CRUD actions, but when I try to call it from inside the angular component it fails. Where is my issue? What did I wrong?

Comment: Check the value of the FK_Childs_Parents_ParentId, the error you get means you're either using a foreign key value that doesn't exist or is illegal - like 0 or null

Comment: Thank you. This hint helped me to find the issue. ParentId Property Name on Entity and on Typescript/Angular Interface wasn't named same by accident.